# The sequence $H_n-\ln(n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

Is there a proof that the sequence $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)$ converges that doesn't use integrals?

Comment: How do you define $\ln x$?

Comment: $\ln{x}=\log_{e}x$, where $e$ is the Euler's number.

Comment: So how do you define $\log_e x$...?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\ln(n+1)-\ln n \to 0$, we can just as well put $\ln(n+1)$ there. Write the sum as 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\left( \frac{1}{k} - \ln \frac{k+1}{k }\right)$$
By Taylor's formula applied to $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$, 
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{2k^2} f''(\xi) $$
where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $1/k$. Since $|f''(\xi)|\le 1$, it follows that 
$$\left|\frac{1}{k} - \ln \frac{k+1}{k }\right| \le \frac{1}{2k^2}$$
which by Comparison test implies that the series
 $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left( \frac{1}{k} - \ln \frac{k+1}{k }\right)$$
converges.

Comment: Why are we able to use the Taylor Expansion of ln, as the radius of convergence is (-1,1)?